# Как определить, является ли год високосным?

Tags: python

> Дано натуральное число. Требуется определить, является ли год с данным номером високосным. Если год является високосным, то выведите YES, иначе выведите NO. Напомним, что в соответствии с григорианским календарем, год является високосным, если его номер кратен 4, но не кратен 100, а также если он кратен 400.

```
i = int(input())

if (i % 4 == 0 or i % 400 == 0) and i % 100 != 0:
    print("YES")
else:
    print("NO")
```

Прошу не показать правильный ответ, а разъяснить в чём моя ошибка и почему код работает не корректно)
Я только учусь, всем заранее спасибо!

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, **конкретную проблему или ошибку**. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. Уточните в вопросе, **что именно на ваш взгляд "работает некорректно"?**

Comment: тут рассказать что неправильно это показать решение. Ошибка в 1 строке.

Comment: Ну не корректность его в том что при некоторых значениях выводит не правильный результат, допустим при таких значениях как: 1600, 2000

Comment: Я думаю можно и посмотреть правильное решение, ибо сам я додуматься не могу...

Comment: ну так если на вход вводить числа кратные 400 условие не выполняется. 400%==0 верно и 400%100 !=0 неверно , поэтому выводит no. Да и в условии конкретно же сказано *год является високосным, если его номер кратен 4, но не кратен 100 , а также(=или) если он кратен 400.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Условие нужно переписать так:

```
if (i % 4 == 0 and i % 100 != 0) or i % 400 == 0:
```

Потому что то условие, которое написали вы, проверяет, что год кратен 400 и одновременно не кратен 100, что, очевидно, не может выполняться.

Answer (score 3):

```
import calendar

print(calendar.isleap(int(input())))
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```
year = int(input())

if year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0:
    print("Високосный")
else:
    print("Обычный")
```

Comment: Ответ отличается от принятого три года назад отсутствием объяснений и скобок в условии.